# How will I disable other users to access a certain form in c# connected to database?

Tags: c#, mysql, database

```
try
{
    conn.Open();

    string sql = "select * from tbl_user where username=@uname and password=@pword ";

    MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
    sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", txtuname.Text);
    sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pword", txtpword.Text);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    string lvl = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
    conn.Close();
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully Logged in as " + lvl);
        this.Hide();
        MainMenu mm = new MainMenu();
        mm.ShowDialog();
    }

}

catch (Exception a)
{
    MessageBox.Show(a.Message);
}
```

this is the code that I have. Its running but I dont know how to disable other users to access some forms except for the admin.

Comment: There are alot of potential solutions to this, but the general consensus will be to have something globally define whether someone is or isnt an admin one logged in.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you're trying to achieve. not just showing some random code and saying I want to disable some forms for some users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you need to maintain **USER ROLES** in your **DATABASE**.

And while logging in ,after successfull login based on the user roles values in the db,you can decide which form you need to show or hide.

user roles in db(example):

[image]

and add a `foreign key` in your userinfo table

[image]

And while logging in get the `usertype` coloumn value,and perform your logic.

```
 try
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    string sql = "select * from tbl_user where username=@uname and password=@pword ";

                    MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
                    sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", txtuname.Text);
                    sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pword", txtpword.Text);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    string lvl = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                     int role=convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[rowindex][coloumnindex].ToString());
                    conn.Close();
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Successfully Logged in as " + lvl);
                        this.Hide();   


                if(role == 1)
                     {
                 //show the page for the corresponding user role.
                     }
                  else if(role == 2)
                      {
                       //show the page for the corresponding user role.
                         }
                 else if(role == 3)
                    {
                    //show the page for the corresponding user role.
                       }   
                    }

                }

                catch (Exception a)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(a.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: His question is about how he goes about form access, not database permissions.

Comment: Thats what i'm saying,based on the roles in db the programmer can write code for deciding displaying forms.

Comment: its the code for the form display he wants help with. Though user management is part of the solution, it isnt the whole solution. That part is particularly broad in scope.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
 try
            {
                string authority="false";
                conn.Open();

                string sql = "select * from tbl_user where username=@uname and password=@pword ";

                MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
                sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", txtuname.Text);
                sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pword", txtpword.Text);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                string lvl = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                conn.Close();
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    authority="true";
                }

                if(authority=="true")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Successfully Logged in as " + lvl);
                    authority=false;
                    this.Hide();
                    MainMenu mm = new MainMenu();
                    mm.ShowDialog();                        
                }
                else
                {
                MessageBox.Show("You are not Authorized user.");
                }

                }

            catch (Exception a)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(a.Message);
            }
```